# Mediawiki magic word or parser function in a template that prints the template's name?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, mediawiki-templates

The context of this question is for tracking which templates transcluded content comes from.

There doesn't appear to be a built-in that does this (see https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words). Most of these related to page titles as you would see in the URL bar.

Here's a hypothetical example of what I'm looking for:

Contents of "Template:Foo"

```
<includeonly>You transcluded Template:{{TEMPLATENAME}}</includeonly>
```

Contents of "Example Page"

```
{{Foo}}
```

What "Example Page" should look like:

```
You transcluded Template:Foo
```

Using {{PAGENAME}} or similar doesn't work because those use the current page they are being applied on. For example, if Template:Foo used {{PAGENAME}} instead of the hypothetical {{TEMPLATENAME}}, then the content of the example page would be "You transcluded Template:Example Page", which would be incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

You can only access it via the parsing frame. The Scribunto extension [makes that available](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto/Lua_reference_manual#frame:getTitle), if you don't use it you'll have to [write your own parser function](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parser_functions) (and declare it with the `SFH_OBJECT_ARGS` option, so the frame gets passed to it).